# Using dissolve tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to calculate the density of agricultural fields in every cell of a square grid 1x1km. I have the fields shapefile and I built up a grid (.shp) with the same extent using fishnet tool. I created an ID field for the grid and then I intersected with the fields shape in order to associate every field (or field part) to a specific grid cell. I then dissolved based on ID allowing for multipart feature, but instead of having only 1 polygon per ID I still have some. Maybe someone faced the same ArcGIS problem and knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Thia may be due to [multipart features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/h-how-dissolve-data-management-works.htm) being checked, uncheck it and re-run, hopefully should resolve your issue!

If you're still having issues I would re-examine your data to see what could be causing this behaviour. If all else fails you can open up editor and ["merge" the polygons together manually](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm).

[image]

Comment: Create multipart feature was checked

Comment: @Lollo did unchecking it give the desired result?

Comment: I found the issue, it was a malfunctioning of ArcGIS due to the amount of data. Trying again with smaller data sets the tool worked fine.